# How to serialize parameter values as JSON property?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, serialization, json.net

I need a JSON string that the JSON key is property value instead of the property name.

I have these classes:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 1;
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Test Group";

    public IEnumerable<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 1;
    public int GroupId { get; set; } = 1;
    public string Key { get; set; } = "Test Key";
    public string Value { get; set; } = "Test Value";
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

And my result has to be like that:

```
{
    "Test Group": {
        "Test Key": "Test Value",
        "Test 2 Key": "Test 2 Value"
    },
    "Group 2": {
        "Key 2": "Value 2"
    }
}
```

Comment: You will not be able to serialize and deserialize data using from json  using your classes. You have to change something  classes or json.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to map a list of `Document`'s to the inner json nodes and map a list of `Group`'s to the outer nodes.  Both of these can be mapped to a `Dictionary` using [`ToDictionary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0).

Assuming you have an enumerable of groups: `var groups = some IEnumerable<Group>`, then the following code produces your desired result:

```
// use ToDictionary on the groups, and on the Documents
var groupDictionary = groups.ToDictionary(g => g.Name, 
                                 g => g.Documents.ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value));

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupDictionary, Formatting.Indented);

// output
{
  "Test Group": {
    "Test Key": "Test Value",
    "Test Key 2": "Test 2 Value"
  },
  "Group 2": {
    "Key 2": "Value 2"
  }
}
```

Where I've used `Newtonsoft.Json` to serialize. If you're using `System.Text.Json` instead you can serialize using:

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize(groupDictionary, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```

Try the [demo online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OPG5gm)